# Page redirects to index.html after on submit when deployed in AWS ampify

Tags: reactjs, react-router, aws-amplify

I have deployed a react app in `AWS amplify`.It works fine in local host but when deployed it seems like react router is not working as expected .i.e when entered the link manually it redirects to `index.html` page. Moreover on submission of a form though i have mentioned `event.preventDefault()` the page redirects to `index.html`

App.js

```
return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">

    <Switch>



    <Route exact path="/SignUp" component={SignVerification}/>

    <Route exact path="/" component={()=><Home BlogInfo={this.state.BlogInfo} onAddUpvote={this.addUpvote} onAddPost={this.addPost}/>} />

        <Route exact path="/One/:id" render={(params)=>(<Single BlogInfo={this.state.BlogInfo}{...params} />)}/>


  </Switch>


    </div>

    </Router>
  );
}
}
```

Post.js

```
  handleSubmit=(event)=>
{

  axios.post("https://3em19ts012.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Dev/comment",

    {Comment :this.state.comments,
    PostId:this.props.match.params.id,
    Time:new Date(),
    Username:userPool.getCurrentUser().getUsername(),
    ParentId:"None"
    }      

).then((response) => {
  var data={comment:response.data.message.Comt.S,
    Username:response.data.message.Username.S
    };
    this.setState({commentInfo:[data,...this.state.commentInfo]})

  });









  event.preventDefault();


this.setState({comments:""})



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AWS amplify redirecting(302) to index.html when its getting a request which results a 404.

I can think of 2 solution:

1. Use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter. or
2. Configure AWS amplify to send [200 redirects (rewrites)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html) when its get a 404

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the page  from reloading

Comment: on form submission you can prevent page reload. Please paste the method you are calling on form submit.

Comment: I have uploaded the  on form submit method,It works fine locally

Comment: It should work. Is it possible to get the link where your app is hosted?

Comment: https://master.df4818z86d6ru.amplifyapp.com/#/home       Go to trending post and click on the any of the heading of those photos and try to add a comment

Comment: move `event.preventDefault()` before `axios.post`. also fix  the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUsername' of null
    at a.handleSubmit (Single.js:61)`